# Why numpy returns true index while comparing integer and float value from two different list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, match

How to avoid returning true index while comparing `10.5` and `10`?

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.5])

B = np.array([1,7,10])

i = np.searchsorted(A,B)

print i   # [0 6 9]
```

I want to get the places of the exact matches: `[0 6]`

Comment: So are you asking for how to avoid returning 9 in then?  Search sorted will always return a value, it's not checking if they are equal, it's telling you where you could insert 10 into the list to maintain its order.

Comment: In this case I want it shall return two index as it is matching exactly at 0 and 6th place .

Comment: Then what is best way to find index when exactly there is a match. And how can I get the indexes of smaller list  so that I can do kind of A[I]-B[j]. Where j is found from match and I is the index of bigger list . Is it possible to get these ?

Comment: And of course in this case it shall return zero

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) with `left` and `right` and only keep those who don't return the same index for both:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.5])
>>> B = np.array([1,7,10])

>>> i = np.searchsorted(A, B, 'left')
>>> j = np.searchsorted(A, B, 'right')
>>> i[i!=j]
array([0, 6], dtype=int64)
```

That works because `searchsorted` returns the index where the element needs to be inserted if you want to keep the other array sorted. So when the value is present in the other array it returns the index before the match (`left`) and the index after the matches(`right`). So if the index differs there's an exact match and if the index is the same there's no exact match

Comment: I have tried   A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.5])    B = np.array([1,7,10])    c=set(A)    indx=[i for i, item in enumerate(B) if item in c]         Now I want to subtract each value of matched index from higher list. the results is ofcourse zero. How to perform A[index]-c[indx]

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Probably better to ask a new question instead of following a different thread in the comments.

Comment: No I am in the same page of the problem . I got indexes but how can I subtract each value of matched indexes from another one. The result ofcourse would be zero

Comment: Yes Sir, I want to implement this

Comment: @Poka It's still not clear to me what you want to do. What exactly should be the result? `[0, 0]` or just `0` or something else? What's the higher list? These are all things that can't be solved in the comments it would be much easier to ask a new question where you exactly state what you want to get and how that would be "determined".

Comment: Once again I am trying to express my thoughts.

Comment: List1= [1,2,3,4,5,10,15.5,20,25];  List2=[0,2,5,10,20],   lets say we got index of list2 [1,2,3,4] or your suggestion i can get indexes  of list1 i.e [1,4,5,8]. After this I want to subtract list1-list2 . But only for matched indexes I want to subtract . kind of List1[i]-List[j].  i is indexes of List1 and j is matched index of list2

Comment: I still don't know what you expect that to return? `[0, 0, 0, 0]`? Or should it happen in-place? Once again: A new question will allow you to have more place and better markup to state the question and much more attention than in a comment thread. So please just ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

First you can help `searchsorted`, since A is sorted, for better complexity:

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.5])
B = np.array([1,7,10])    
i = np.searchsorted(A,B,sorter=range(len(A)))
```

then `in1d` can find the exact correspondence :

```
j = i[np.in1d(A[i],B,True)]
# [0,6]
```

Comment: Thanks . I got the indices correctly. But problem is one is list of let say length 10 and another is list of length of 7. And there is a match of 5 elements. I can get index of either lower list or higher list. But now how can I subtract each matched indexes from another